# Need some guidance on testing strategies for Laravel 4 application

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, laravel

I've written a fairly simple Laravel application (a REST API which talks to an AngularJS frontend), but I'm having some trouble getting my head around how to test it. I've never done any real testing before, and after reading up on unit testing, TDD, etc I feel like I have a good sense of the broad strategies behind it, but I'm just having trouble with actually implementing it on my code.

I'm starting with unit testing, and here is the class I want to test:

```
class ShippingRunRepository
{
    public function getActiveRuns()
    {
        $runs = ShippingRun::with(['carrierAccount', 'carrierAccount.carrier', 'carrierAccount.carrier.carrierSteps'])
            ->where('accountID', '=', \Auth::user()->accountID)
            ->where('active', '=', 1)
            ->get()
            ->filter(function ($run) {
                if ($run->carrierAccount && $run->carrierAccount->carrier && $run->carrierAccount->carrier->carrierSteps) {
                    foreach ($run->carrierAccount->carrier->carrierSteps as $step) {
                        if ($step->shippingStep->stepCode == 'printLabelsApp') {
                            return $run;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        return Paginator::make($runs->all(), $runs->count(), 15);
    }
}
```

So here are my thoughts on this, if you can let me know if I'm on the right track that would be great:

- I assume I need to mock the dependencies somehow (ShippingRun, Auth, Paginator) - I attempted to inject them in the constructor but ran into some issues, though if this is the right way to go I'll obviously try again
- Do I need to refactor this code further, and test each function individually? I'm not really sure how to go about that either.
- I've seen some tests for a class like this which test that the Eloquent object itself receives certain calls (where, get, etc) - isn't this breaking the rule of testing the implementation of a call like this, rather than the functionality?

Any advice you can give would be great! I would also love to see the source of an application written in Laravel that has some good tests written, I learn a lot better by looking at code in a real situation. Does anybody know where I might find that?

Comment: To answer your second bullet point, the main principle of writing tests is to "only test your own stuff" by this we mean, that we are going to assume that all the laravel functions actually work correctly (whether rightly or wrongly) so your test only needs to be about making sure the number of results comes out correctly.

Comment: OK, that makes sense - to properly unit test I assume I shouldn't hit the database though, so I guess I need to mock the ShippingRun and Paginate objects, and just tell them to return specific data? I guess my question at this point is, what am I even testing? This function relies completely on Laravel classes, so if I mock them up to give back specific data, what is the test achieving? I feel like there's a key idea that I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume I need to mock the dependencies somehow (ShippingRun, Auth, Paginator)

You should inject the ShippingRun object in your constructor. This is what will alllow you to mock it in your tests.

Auth and Paginator are full-fledged Laravel facades and can be mocked this way: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#mocking-facades

> I've seen some tests for a class like this which test that the Eloquent object itself receives certain calls (where, get, etc) - isn't this breaking the rule of testing the implementation

You're on the right track. Assuming ShippingRun is an Eloquent model, you can mock it and write shouldReceive()->times()->with() expectations for its methods. What you'll end up testing is that ShippingRun is receiving the proper data and that getActiveRuns is returning a call to the Paginator facade. You don't need to concern yourself with the rest.

That being said, having your Eloquent models receive calls in tests can work if you're more concerned about Integration Tests than Unit Tests. It will still insure that your code is working but it will make your tests tightly coupled with Eloquent. An eventual problem if you eventually want to move away from pure Laravel code.

> Does anybody know where I might find that?

https://laracasts.com/index/testing